# Grails Data Base Migration - dbm-gorm-diff is not working

Tags: grails, database-migration, grails-2.3

I am using Grails 2.3.5 with database migration plugin in new project for understand how it is working. But sometimes dbm-gorm-diff provide empty changelog file,even changes is there.
For example,

i have the person domain class with out any properties.
When initially creating change log, it will create 2 fields id and version in change log.
After that, added 2fields name,age into that person class. then did dbm-update and dbm-gorm-diff that give like following.

databaseChangeLog = {
}

Sometimes gives the changes. some times is not working. Please help me. Why it is working like that. Sorry for bad english.

Comment: I am not very familiar with the database migration plugin. According to the documentation it says that you initially should run `dbm-generate-gorm-changelog` to generate the change log form your domain classes. It also says if `To create the changelog additions, you can either manually create the changes or with the dbm-gorm-diff script`

Comment: Ya. Initially i run the command and got initial change log.After that modified the Domain, that will not come in new changelog and also we can create changelog manually .Can't we use dbm-gorm-diff always? In which scenarios i will use manual creation and dbm-gorm-diff.

Comment: Have you tried this tutorial? http://assarconsulting.blogspot.ch/2011/08/database-migration-in-grails.html

Comment: Are you using the Grails shell or are you executing each dbm-* command individually, loading the Grails environment each time with each command call?

Answer (score 5):

Using the following [tutorial](http://assarconsulting.blogspot.ch/2011/08/database-migration-in-grails.html) works for me. Make sure you remove `dbCreate` from your `DataSource.groovy`. According to the [tutorial](http://assarconsulting.blogspot.ch/2011/08/database-migration-in-grails.html) the workflow is as follows:

## Setup

1. Remove `dbCreate` from `DataSource.groovy`
2. Initially run `grails dbm-generate-gorm-changelog changelog.groovy`
3. Sync the changelog with your db by running `grails dbm-changelog-sync`

## Changing domain

1. Change domain class
2. Run `grails dbm-gorm-diff <your-filename>.groovy --add`
3. Run `grails dbm-changelog-sync`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

I have spent some time searching for the answer to this same issue.

**Caveat:** I am using the Grails interactive shell to issue commands, including the `dbm-*` commands.

By brute force alone, I have come to the conclusion that the domain classes are not reliably reloading.  To get consistent results (especially with the generation of new `changeLog` files), any time I modify a domain class, I stop and restart the Grails interactive shell before calling `dbm-gorm-diff`.  I've tried issuing other commands like `clean`, `compile`, `package` and `refresh-dependencies` and they just aren't working, and the `-reloading` flag at the start up of the Grails interactive shell doesn't seem to make any difference either.

Restarting the Grails interactive shell, however, does seem to work reliably, thought it galls me to do so :)

Those who do not use the interactive shell should not be having this problem since the domain classes are loaded with every command call.

Comment: I've hit this same thing. I leave the interactive shell running and use a second console tab to issue the dbm-gorm-* commands from a bare command line.

Answer (score 2):

This **[blog](http://fbflex.wordpress.com/2011/01/19/working-with-the-grails-database-migration-plugin/)** has detailed step by step explanation, specially **Migrating old databases** section helped us in migrating successfully.